# Can I use html templates without a Content Manager System?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to web development. I've learned a bit of Flask and Django and I discovered a very useful feature: using templates so as not to repeat the same code on every html page.

Is it possible to use this feature without a content manager such as Django or Flask though?

It is very complicated to install those on the server hosting my website; besides, I would have to change for a more professional (expensive) scheme. I wish to stick with html, css and javascript.

Thanks for your advice,
Al

Comment: many clientside frameworks like vue can be rendered into a static html and still be fully dynamic with multiple pages and structured modules, templates and code, you could even use one of the many templates engines like ejs, or look into web components or go really hacky and use ajax to load partials.. yes is possible you dont need serverside to include things

Comment: If you just want template functionality, with the outcome of a static site, perhaps look at systems like [`Jekyll`](https://jekyllrb.com/) or [`Lektor`](https://www.getlektor.com/).  The former is based on Ruby on Rails, and has a similar template system to Jinja used by Flask.  The latter I haven't used, but is used by the Flask development team to create their own site `palletsprojects.com`.